# Kendo Upload is not uploading template in CSHTML

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using a kendo upload as follows

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("files")
            .TemplateId("fileTemplate2")
            .Async(a => a
                .Save("Save", "SignOff")
                .Remove("Remove", "SignOff")
                .AutoUpload(true)
            )
            .Events(events => events.Upload("onUpload"))
  )
```

and my template is like this

```
<script id="fileTemplate2" type="text/x-kendo-template">
                <span class='k-progress'></span>
                <div class='file-wrapper'>                    
                    <h4 class='file-heading file-name-heading'>Name: #=name#</h4>
                    <h4 class='file-heading file-size-heading'>Size: #=size# bytes</h4>
                    <button type='button' class='k-upload-action'></button>
                </div>
</script>
```

I've actually put template on top of the upload declaration. But upload is not loading the template. Please help where am I doing wrong.

```
<link href="../../Content/kendo/upload.kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../Content/kendo/upload.kendo.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../../Scripts/kendo/kendocdn.kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the dll. I think that will resolve your problem.